# pip broke after uninstalling a module

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I used pip uninstall on shapely and got an exception, which I did not save.
Since then every pip or easy install command will pop this exception :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pip.compat import console_to_str, stdlib_pkgs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip.compat.dictconfig import dictConfig as logging_dictConfig
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\dictconfig.py", line 22, in <module>
    import logging.handlers
  File "C:\Python27\lib\logging\handlers.py", line 27, in <module>
    import logging, socket, os, cPickle, struct, time, re
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: No module named _socket
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of python exactly?

Comment: python version : 2.7.1

Comment: Can you install 2.7.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [bug](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/727).

Off the top, `pip uninstall shapely` seems to be removing the top dlls from the Python installations. This is why you see the error on every pip command after.

Comment: It should, seems like the bug is not fixed yet. Accept the answer in case it is what you were looking for.